# Is there a way to make a UITextField move when user drags across screen?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm new to coding so I'm trying some small projects in swift. Right now, I'm trying to make a text box inside the ViewController move when the user drags it along the screen. For the text box, I am currently using a UITextField but I have no idea how to program its movement according to drag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to your view. There's all sorts of built in gesture recognizers for detecting various gestures like a tap or in this case a pan (drag). You can check them out here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer

Here we'll create a pan gesture recognizer, and add it to our view. Assume myView is your UITextField. A good place to do this is in your view controller's viewDidLoad() method.

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(sender:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

The moment your finger touches the screen, we say that a touch sequence has begun. The touch sequence ends when there are no more fingers on the screen. The pan gesture will determine if this touch sequence looks like a pan, and if so, the method handlePan will be called at various stages. Here, the gesture itself will be passed into the method, which we use to determine translation and move our view accordingly. Add this as a method of your view controller.

```
@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
    self.myView.center.x += translation.x
    self.myView.center.y += translation.y
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)
}
```

The first line gets the translation in the view which the gesture is attached to (myView). We then adjust myView's position based on this translation, and then we set the translation to zero. This is so that the next time this method is called, the translation will be a delta relative to the previous call.

The property `sender.state` will tell you the state the gesture is currently in, for example, `.began`, `.changed`, `.ended`. Since a pan is a continuous gesture, our method will be called many times, whenever there's a finger movement.

Comment: is it possible to create a uniform handlePan function for more than 1 UITextField?

Comment: Totally. In fact, it's already like that, almost. All we need to do is change self.myView to sender.view, which is the view the gesture is attached to. Then you can create lots of pan gestures and attach one to each of your views you want to make draggable, and all of them can use the same handlePan method.

Comment: So a warning tells me I should use sender.view? or sender.view!. But trying out both, the pan gesture seems to register only on the last UITextField that was given the gesture.

Comment: You have to create a new gesture recognizer for each one; don't attach the same gesture recognizer instance.

Comment: sender.view is an optional because the gesture stores it's view as a weak reference. Meaning, if the view deinits, sender.view will be nil. So be safe and access it with a ?